# Visual Studio load test results repository is out of space

Tags: c#, visual-studio, testing

Running my Visual Studio load tests results in the following error message:

> Error occurring running test. Results collection stopped due to the following error. Could not access the load test results repository. The load test results repository is out of space. Allocate more space to the repository (if possible), or delete results of older load test runs.

I'm not aware of any such repository. How do I find the repository and fix the problem?

Comment: How big is the SQL server database that the load test system is using?

Comment: @Lasse: As far as I know the test system isn't using any database. How do I find out?

Comment: I have no idea, I just did a google search for `visual studio load test repository space`, and this page popped out: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms318550.aspx, it mentions that a SQL Server Express server is installed and a database is set up, and those can only become 4GB with that version apparently. See the topic "Load test results store considerations" on that page. That's all I know, but it might be enough to point you in the right direction.

Comment: It appears you can create (or perhaps migrate/move?) that database on a real SQL Server instance, which would not have those limitations, and never express editions have a higher limit, I believe its 10GB now on the 2012 version (http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/editions/2012-editions/express.aspx), but I have no idea if you can use that database engine for your needs. I'm not familiar with the load test system at all unfortunately.

Comment: If you figure out what to fix, you might want to write up an answer to your own question here, I'm sure someone else will have the same question at some point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To make more room in the database, open any load test [see note]. Right click in the load test and select **manage test results**, or click the next-to-rightmost icon above the load test pane. One of the drop-down lists in the window allows the selection of all load test results. Select one or more result files that are no longer wanted and **remove** them. Removal takes a while, possibly minutes.

Load test results can be archived and restored via the **export** and **import** buttons on the same window. Exporting does not remove the results.

Note: Can also create a new load test, it does not need to do anything, it just needs to exist. The only way to access the **manage test results** window is via an open load test.

Update:

The SQL database that Visual Studio is using can be found from Menu => **Load Test** => **Manage test controllers**.

---

The database that is being used is not always obvious and sometimes the **Manage Test Controllers** window does not tell the whole story. Hence the database from which results should be deleted is not obvious. In one case I found the message below was repeatedly displayed even though all the records in the load tests database found using **Manage Test Controllers** had been deleted.

> Results collection stopped due to the following error:
>   Could not access the load test results repository: The
>   load test results repository is out of space.  Allocate
>   more space to the repository (if possible), or delete
>   results of older load test runs.

In the **Open and Manage Load Test Results** window I recommend checking every value shown in the **Enter a controller name to find load test results** (including the value `<Local - No controller>`) and for each of these values set **Show results for the following load test** to be `<Show results for all tests>`.

Answer (score 1):

AdrianHHH's post is correct, but just to clarify: "Open Load test" means open the load test *designer*, not a result. You then right click on any of the nodes in the designer. In Visual Studio 2017 the context menu after you right click says "Open and Manage Results."

If you get the error about not being able access the results store, then go to SQL Server DB and shrink the database (Rt click on DB node -- > Tasks -- > Shrink --> Files (and also DB)).

My strategy is to delete the small runs first, which you can find by sorting the results on their Duration column.

[image]