# VS Load Tests without database

Tags: visual-studio, testing, load-testing, visual-studio-2017, msloadtest

I have a load test, but it wants to save data in a database.  We're still 'getting started' and really want the results either on the screen or in a file right now.

How do I tell the load test **not** to write to a database and to just show me the results instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the properties of the "Run settings" set the `Storage type` to be `None`.

I do not recommend doing this. Much of the result detail is not preserved or graphed properly when not saved to the database. For the same reason I normally run test with the `Timing details storage` property of the "Run settings" set to `All individual details`.

The database is not large and the results from unwanted runs can easily be deleted. See also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16635891/546871) and [here](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/a/14503/6752) for some notes on managing the results database.

Comment: Thanks.  Its only very short term to prove the rest run as expected.

Comment: My 'Run Settings' doesn't have anything in the properties window.

Comment: Ignore that.  They're in "Run Settings 1 [Active[".